# Help in deriving proof with exponential and little-oh

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-sum

I'm working through a proof of the Kelly Criterion found at http://www.elem.com/~btilly/kelly-criterion/. In checking up on some of the derivations I can't follow the last step in this sequence (equation below marked [*]):

(Note, $X_i$ is a random variable, E(X) is expectation of X)

$$
w_n=w_oX_1X_2...X_n\\
w_n=e^{log{(w_oX_1X_2...X_n)}}\\
w_n=e^{log(w_o) +  log(X_1) + log(X_2) + ... + log(X_n)} [1]\\
$$

Using the law of large numbers:
$ log(X_1) + log(X_2) + ... + log(X_n) = E(log(X))n + o(n)$

[o(n) is little-oh notation]

which reduces [1] to 
$$
w_n=e^{log(w_0) +  E(log(X))n + o(n)}\\
w_n=e^{log(w_0) +  E(log(X))n + o(1)n}\\
w_n=w_0 e^{(E(log(X)) + o(1))n}\\
w_n=w_0(e^{(E(log(X))}(1+ o(1)))^n [*]\\
$$

That last step [*] is where I get lost. Isn't that the equivalent of saying:

$$
e^{k + o(1)} = e^k(1+o(1))
$$

, where $k = E(log(X))$?

I don't see how to make that leap.

Any help appreciated.